# How to create slow simultaneous transitions of multiple attributes in force directed graphs?

Tags: d3.js, transition, force-layout

In a previous post called "[D3: How to create slow transition of Circles for nodes in Force Directed Graphs FDG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603294/d3-how-to-create-slow-transition-of-circles-for-nodes-in-force-directed-graphs/17604463?noredirect=1#17604463)", I got a great answer for how to transition a single element (e.g. the radius for "just circles") in D3.

My followup question is now about how to transition "multiple D3 attributes" at the same time...

As a reminder, I'm using D3 generated Radio Buttons to toggle the size of Nodes in a FDG Layout (on mouse click) from a default size to a scaled magnitude. You can find the Radio Buttons in the upper left hand of the [Node Cluster Diagram](http://nounz.if4it.com/Nouns/Applications/A__Application_1.NodeCluster.html) (http://nounz.if4it.com/Nouns/Applications/A__Application_1.NodeCluster.html)

The code that toggles the node circles between a default number and a scaled magnitude (now using transitions) looks as follows...

```
    var densityControlClick = function() {

      var thisObject = d3.select(this);
      var typeValue = thisObject.attr("density_type");
      var oppositeTypeValue = (function() {
        if(typeValue=="On") {
          return "Off";
        } else {
          return "On";
        }
      })();

      var densityBulletSelector = "." + "densityControlBullet-" + typeValue;
      var selectedBullet = d3.selectAll(densityBulletSelector);
      selectedBullet.style("fill", "Black") 

      var oppositeDensityBulletSelector = "." + "densityControlBullet-" + oppositeTypeValue;
      var selectedOppositeBullet = d3.selectAll(oppositeDensityBulletSelector);
      selectedOppositeBullet.style("fill", "White") 

      if(typeValue=="On") {
        var selectedNodeCircles = d3.selectAll("#NODE");
        selectedNodeCircles.transition().duration(500).attr("r", function(d){ return rRange(d.rSize); });
      }
      else {
        var selectedNodeCircles = d3.selectAll("#NODE");            selectedNodeCircles.transition().duration(500).attr("r", function(d) { if (d.id==focalNodeID) { return centerNodeSize; } else { return defaultNodeSize; } } );
      }

    }
```

Everything works great and you can see the slower node transitions when you select the radio buttons.  However, I'd now like to learn how to transition multiple elements, such as the the radius and the edge lengths simultaneously, along with the theory behind doing so, in order to show off D3's dynamic nature.

My question is: Given that I already can successfully transition the radius of circles, how would I also transition other elements like the edge lengths based on attributes like "alpha", "friction", etc., and... what's the theory behind transitioning multiple elements (in other words, what does the code mean, in English)?  The D3 API doesn't appear to clearly get into the theory behind transitioning multiple attributes, simultaneously.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So transitioning multiple attributes is the simple part of this question. Just like a regular selection you can set multiple attributes at a time on your transition:

```
selectedNodeCircles.transition().duration(500)
    .attr("r", function(d){ return rRange(d.rSize); })
    .attr("stroke", 'red');
```

This will transition your radius and your line colour. The transition is a property of the DOM element (in this case the circle) and it will transition as many DOM attributes as you like. The thing to remember is that there is only only one transition object on each DOM element. So if you create another you will overwrite the old one.

```
// This will NOT work
circles.transition().duration(1000).attr('r', 50);
// The radius transition will be overridden by the fill 
// transition and so will not complete
circles.transition().duration(1000).attr('fill', 'red');
```

This can actually be quite useful because you don't have to worry about interrupting animations that are in progress and figure out how far along they are and then starting a new animation - this will generally be handled automatically.

In your case you want to transition edge lengths in your graph. These are determined by the positional attributes of the nodes. Judging by your finished product, these attributes are already being animated because you are updating the DOM on every iteration of the layout algorithm (not through transitions) probably in the tick() callback.

So you could use transitions inside your tick callback, which might look odd and may be a hassle to keep in synch with the radius transitions (you will have to set both attributes in the transition). But it might be just what you need.

Alternatively, if you can wait, don't update the DOM in the tick callback. Let the layout complete - it runs a lot faster when it is not rendering on each tick - and once it is complete you can animate the radius and x and y attributes to their final positions. Of course this means you'll want good starting positions.